# Guidelines on learning database internals

Tags: database-design

I have been a developer for the past couple of years and now i am interested in learning more about the internals of database systems. I figure one of the best place to start is to do a deep dive into SQL, from a technical point of view - so understanding the syntax and semantics, and understanding the query engine bit and how a database system takes the sql, and parse it into things like query plan.

So to start with this, I looked into SQL parsing and found this library https://github.com/sqlparser-rs/sqlparser-rs

I ran the example but using a much simpler query, basically this

```
use sqlparser::dialect::GenericDialect;
use sqlparser::parser::Parser;

let sql = "SELECT * from table_1";

let dialect = GenericDialect {}; // or AnsiDialect, or your own dialect ...

let ast = Parser::parse_sql(&dialect, sql).unwrap();

println!("AST: {:?}", ast);
```

And the output was

```
AST: [Query(Query { with: None, body: Select(Select { distinct: false, top: None, projection: [Wildcard(WildcardAdditionalOptions { opt_exclude: None, opt_except: None, opt_rename: None, opt_replace: None })], into: None, from: [TableWithJoins { relation: Table { name: ObjectName([Ident { value: "table_1", quote_style: None }]), alias: None, args: None, with_hints: [] }, joins: [] }], lateral_views: [], selection: None, group_by: [], cluster_by: [], distribute_by: [], sort_by: [], having: None, qualify: None }), order_by: [], limit: None, offset: None, fetch: None, locks: [] })]
```

Now this is where my question starts, I know this is an AST, but I don't know what this means. Specifically

1. I don't know how to read this and make meaning out of it
2. I don't understand what I can do with it. Can I modify it? Can I transform it
3. I don't understand how to know if it is valid or not
4. I do not understand what a database system use a data-structure like this and what to do with it next

So obviously a newbie questions, but will appreciate if I can get some early guidelines to help in this learning path.

Answer (score 0):

Well... You went by a very long road...

If you want to know database internals, for the purposes of be a good database developer - it would be enough to write SQL queries. Lots and lots of different SQL queries with different optimization plans. That is one set of skills.

The [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) provided by parser is a completely different problem which would be useful if you start creating your own database system. Starting with a flat files or simple arrays. How to find some value in that array? Or how to gather subset of data from flat file? Once you know how to do it from an algorithmic point of view, you can start developing API to call these algorithms. And finally, you will use a parser, which takes a source code written by a human and transforms it into AST which will tell your database engine which API function to call and in which order.

If, instead of SQL and existing parser, you decide to go with your own query language, then you would write [CFG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) for the parser, which can produce the very same AST. If you already have a parser, then you can ignore CFG for now, but for the purpose of checking "is this AST is correct?" you just need to take the CFG ... and check.

All this CFG-AST stuff is usually studied in the course of "make your own language and/or compiler". It is not really needed for a good database developer.